# Can you get out of text edit in GIMP without choosing a different layer or tool?

Tags: gimp

Is there a key combination I can use to exit text editing?  The only way I can current get out of text editing is by clicking another layer, or clicking another tool in the toolbox.

Is there a keyboard shortcut to finish editing text?

Comment: In Windows version you can close the text tool by hitting Esc key. Does it works for you?

Comment: @PaoloGibellini how strange, I swear I'd already tried that and it didn't work, but trying it now works just fine!

Comment: Please make than an answer and accept it, there's no need for this question to stick around unanswered forever.

Comment: @PaoloGibellini if you add that as an answer I'll select it

Comment: @StaffordWilliams I'm sorry, but yesterday I was away ;-) but the answer of Takkat is correct too.

Comment: Don't know why someone voted your question down, this was very helpful to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way Gimp works is that it does create a new layer for text. We can exit text editing mode by hitting <kbd>ESC</kbd> or selecting another tool but then we will still work on the newly created text layer.

In case we want to work in another (e.g. background) layer we still have to manually select that layer to continue. As this can be done by clicking on a layer e.g. with the zoom tool, it is much more consistent to select a layer using <kbd>Page Up</kbd> resp. <kbd>Page Down</kbd> or the layer dialog (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to show).

Flattening the image will of course also remove the text layer but this is at the cost of no longer being able to edit text.